# In metric space, correct me if I am on the wrong way.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subseteq X$. For $x \in X$, define $d(x,A)$ = inf {$d(x,a):a \in A$}. If $d(x,A) = 0$, $\forall x \in X$. Then which of the following assertions must be true ?

1. $A$ is compact.
2. $A$ is closed.
3. $A$ is dense in $X$
4. $A = X$

If I take $X = [0,1]$ and $A = (0,1)$ such that $d(x,a) = 0$, $\forall x \in X$

Here $X \neq A$. So option 4 is false.

Also $A = (0,1)$ is open. Hence options 1,2 are false.

I think option 3 must be true. How can prove it?

I konw that $A$ is dense in $X$ if $\bar A = X$

Since $\forall x \in X$, $d(x,a) = 0 \implies x \in A$
So $X \subseteq A$....(1) but $A \subseteq X$....(2) given. Hence from (1) and (2) , we get $\bar A = X$

Comment: Right, 3 is the correct one. A word of warning: you said that, since $A$ is open, it cannot be closed and it cannot be compact. This is true in your example, but can be false in more general metric spaces.

Comment: I don't understand the last line, the one that starts with "Since".

Comment: @Gae. S. Given that $d(x,A) = 0$, $\forall x \in X$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro, I couldn't understand the "warning"

Comment: @Merabhai if $X=A=[0,1]$, then $A$ is both open, closed and compact at the same time. So $A$ being open doesn't automatically make it non-closed or non-compact. That's what the warning means.

Comment: I know that , If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then $X$ is clopen but I'm confusing here [0,1] is not open.

Comment: @Mera bhai: Subspaces are not doors. They can be open and closed at the same time :)

Comment: @Merabhai In the metric space $[0,1]$ with the standard metric, the subset $[0,1]$ is definitely open.

Comment: Sets are not intrinsically open or closed. $[0,1]$ is not an open subset of the space $\Bbb R$ but any space is an open subset of itself.  A topological space is a pair $(X,T) $ where $T$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X$, such that $T$ satisfies some certain rules. $T$ is called a topology on $X$ and the members of $T$ are called open sets. It is common to say "the space $X$" without specifying $T$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let us prove that $$ X=\bar A$$

we know that $ \bar A \subset X$.

let $ x\in X$.

$$d(x,A)=0\implies$$
$$ \inf \{d(x,b) , b\in A\}=\color{red}{0}$$

$$\implies$$
$$ (\forall \epsilon>0)\;(\exists a\in A)\;:\;  d(x,a)<\color{red}{0}+\epsilon$$

$$\implies x\in \bar A$$

Answer (score 0):

$d(x, A) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \overline{A}$, so (3) is immediate.